# Powershell Exact search results

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fine tune my script and wanted to see if I could get alittle help with it.  I currently have the script worked out for a search of files in the input directory, but it picks up parts of the search terms rather than an exact match.  Example...  I am searching for rob but my search return rob, robert, and roberta...   I need to make sure that when I search for rob, it only returns rob.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Requests the loctation of the files to search
$Location = Read-Host 'What is the folder location of the files you want to search?'    

#Sets the location based off of the above variable
Set-Location $Location 

#1. Goes thru all the files and subfiles looking for all .sql
$ItemList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Location -Filter *.sql -Recurse;

#2. Define the search parameters
$Search1 = Read-Host 'First Object Name?';
$Search2 = Read-Host 'Second Object Name?';

#3. For each item returned in step 1, check to see if it matches both strings
foreach ($Item in $ItemList) {
$Content = $null = Get-Content -Path $Item.FullName -Raw;
if ($Content -match $Search1 -and $Content -match $Search2) {
    Write-Host -Object ('File ({0}) matched both search terms' -f $Item.FullName);
}
}

#Sets location back to root
Set-Location C:

Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."

$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Comment: Is  there some nameing syntax being used? What should it return if $serach1 is 'rob' and $search2 is 'berta'?

Comment: Basically it is used to find a document that has multiple search terms.  I use this to search SQL files for the table name, and the column name.  If the file has both the tablename and the columnname, then that is what I want to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For exact matches you need to match word boundaries (`\b`):

```
if ($Content -match "\b$Search1\b" -and $Content -match "\b$Search2\b") {
  ...
}
```

There are some characters (so-called metacharacters) that have a special meaning in regular expressions, e.g. `\`, `^`, or square brackets. If you want everything in your search terms to be treated as literal characters you should consider escaping those terms before using them in the conditional:

```
$Search1 = [regex]::Escape($Search1)
$Search2 = [regex]::Escape($Search2)
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks for the quick response Ansgar.  I knew it was something simple, just wasn't sure how to accomplish.

Comment: To make it perfect, you should regex-escape the user input first to support special characters. You never know what users might do :-) `$Content -match "\b$([regex]::Escape($Search1))\b" ....`

Comment: Powershell + Sql imply Sql Server, in which brackets are used when object name is a reserved word or has spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have included it, just in case...lol